# Impact of a predictor becomes opposite in multiple logistic regression model

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

When I am modeling my dependent variable(continuous) on single independent variable(continuous), the predictor is impacting the dependent variable in a positive way. But, when I am modeling the same dependent variable on multiple independent variables, the independent variable which impacted positively when modeled individually is impacting negatively in the final model with several independent variables.What could be the reason for this?Any views would be of great help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox

Answer (score 2):

This might happen when your 'independent' variables are in fact correlated with each other. Simplified example:

```
y = x2-x1
x2 = 2*x1+e
which means y = x1+e (where e is random noise)
```

Learning regression model y=f(x1) will give us positive weight for x1, while learning y=f(x1,x2) will likely give negative weight for the same variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Is it okay if the coefficients filps sign or do we have to do something to rectify it?

Comment: It depends. I'd test for multicollinearity ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity ) and if it is high do something (exclude highly correlated variables, transform data using say PCA,...)